# How to process elements of an OCAML list?

Tags: list, ocaml

I want to process the data present in file "persons.txt".
But i have tried everything to process all the lines from text file.

The only way i can process data is by creating the list manually.

```
let myList = ["John"; "23"]
```

I want the program to iterate through all the lines of the text file.
I have managed a way to pass all the content of the text file into a list but i can+t seem to move on from that stage.

My way of thinking is:

1. Read content from text file
2. Convert to OCaml list
3. Separate list into sublists
4. Iterate through sublists
5. Only print to screen text respecting conditions

Can you please guide me?

Thanks!!

```
open Printf

(* FILE CONTENTS *)
(*
John;23;
Mary;16;
Anne;21;
*)

let file = "data/persons.txt"
;;

(* READ FROM EXTERNAL FILE *)
let read_lines name : string list =
  if Sys.file_exists (name) then
    begin
      let ic = open_in name in
      try
        let try_read () =
          try Some (input_line ic) 
          with End_of_file -> None 
        in
        let rec loop acc = 
          match try_read () with
          | Some s -> loop (s :: acc)
          | None -> close_in_noerr ic; List.rev acc 
        in
        loop []
      with 
        e -> close_in_noerr ic;[]
    end
  else
    []
;;

(...)
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened when you tried it? How was that different from what you were expecting? Also, tip: in OCaml source code you don't need to end everything with `;;`.

Comment: This code works, but it works only with given list, already parsed.
How can i work the text file so that all the content is parsed into lists and then, put through the below conditions?

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way that existing answers stop making sense. And removing all code once you feel you're done is generally considered vandalization on SO.

Comment: You could be interested by parser generators for Ocaml, such as [menhir](http://cambium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/). Before using it, you'll need to read [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)) and the documentation of Menhir and of Ocaml. Spend several days in reading. You also could study (for inspiration) the source code of Ocaml, it is open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear. Here are some observations:

First, your `read_lines` function doesn't return the input in the form you need.

What `read_lines` returns looks like this:

```
["John;23;"; "Mary;16;"; "Anne;21;"]
```

But what you want is something more like this:

[("John", "23)";  ("Mary", "16"); ("Anne", "21")]

The key here is to split the strings into pieces using `;` as a separator. You can probably use `String.split_on_char` for this.

Second, you are not defining a function to calculate an answer from paramters. Instead your calculation is based on global variables. This won't generalize.

Instead of saying this:

```
 let adult_check_condition = 
     ... using global age and name ...
```

You need to define a function:

```
let adult_check_condition age name =
     ... use parameters age and name ...
```

Then you can call this function with different ages and names.

Comment: Will this do the work?

let rec split_string l = match l with
 | []  -> []
 | x::xs -> (Str.split (Str.regexp "[;]+") x)::split_string xs
;;

Comment: It looks good to me. What happens when you try it?

Comment: I've updated the main code in my question.
I get the folllowing error when i try to printf the resulting list:

File "./sample.ml", line 57, characters 19-30:
57 |       show_results people_list
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string list list
       but an expression was expected of type string list
       Type string list is not compatible with type string

Comment: It's not really possible to help without seeing the code. You should open a new question if you still need help. A StackOverflow question is supposed to be asked, answered, and saved for future reference. You shouldn't be modifying the question as you make progress. This doesn't help people with the same questions in the future.